# How to link long press to move script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I found this script: https://unity3d.college/2018/01/30/unity3d-ugui-hold-click-buttons/

I am using Vuforia btw.

I was wondering how to link it to my movement script.

```
   using UnityEngine;

    public class MyDragBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
    {
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == 
    TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            // create ray from the camera and passing through the touch 
    position:
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            // create a logical plane at this object's position
            // and perpendicular to world Y:
            Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
            float distance = 0; // this will return the distance from the camera
            if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
            { // if plane hit...
                Vector3 pos = ray.GetPoint(distance); // get the point
                transform.position = pos;                                      
    // pos has the position in the plane you've touched
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

The current movement script will move my object instantly to where the tap happened on screen. I would like to have it so that you have to long press the object before moving it to avoid having the object jump around on screen.

*EDIT*

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MyDragBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{


float pointerDownTimer = 0;
const float requiredHoldTime = 0.5f; //has to hold for 0.5 seconds

void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            pointerDownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (pointerDownTimer >= requiredHoldTime)
            {
                pointerDownTimer = 0;

                if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())

                    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                    {
                        // create ray from the camera and passing through the touch position:
                        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                        // create a logical plane at this object's position
                        // and perpendicular to world Y:
                        Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
                        float distance = 0; // this will return the distance from the camera
                        if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
                        { // if plane hit...
                            Vector3 pos = ray.GetPoint(distance); // get the point
                            transform.position = pos;                                      // pos has the position in the plane you've touched
                        } //whatever happens when you click

                    }
        }
        else
        {
            pointerDownTimer = 0;
        }
    }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement a simple timer, that increases when you press and resets when you release:

```
float pointerDownTimer = 0;
const float requiredHoldTime = 0.5f //has to hold for 0.5 seconds

void Update(){
    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
       pointerDownTimer += Time.deltaTime; 

       if (pointerDownTimer >= requiredHoldTime){

           ...... //whatever happens when you click

       }
    } else{
       pointerDownTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated OP. I tried the code in the edit but now I can't get the drag behaviour to work.

Comment: i edited the answer so the dragging should work. Just don't set the pointerDownTimer to 0 right after it is greater than `requiredHoldTime`

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a go and now I can't spawn my object. I'm using vuforia btw.

Comment: Should be an unrelated bug, gl hf

Comment: Wait, in the new code, that you posted just remove the 3 consecutive lines `pointerDownTimer = 0;`and `if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())`and `if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)` and it should work fine, no?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I gave it a go, but still the issue of not spawning my object. I'm quite sure this is now vuforia related.